# facebook sdk- how to activate facebook login setup?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to use facebook login in my react-native project. From the facebook developers website, I added a new app and followed the instructions. But for some reason I can't complete the process.

[image]

Notice that in the right project `MoNyang` it is activated. but on the left, its still not activated. I finished the instructions but still like this. Any ideas why?

Comment: you need to add more details. for example, a screenshot of the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though I had completed the guideline from [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started), I had to actually login with my device or simulator.